# Canon Bubble Jet 330 drivers for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

Is there drivers for a Canon BJ 330 printer for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

The official site seems to only list drivers for 98 and down, [Softpedia](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/PRINTER/CANON/Canon-BJ-330-132.shtml) purports to have a driver that is compatible with more than just that (including Vista) -- more than likely, if the driver works with Vista, it will be compatible in entirety with Windows 7. I would, however, be wary of downloading drivers from a site which isn't moderated by the printer manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks,I see what you saying, will decide if I will download or not.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to your query, I have found out how to get the bj330 to print in win 7 64 bit, as follows:
The printer can emulate an IBM proprinter xl24, or an Epson LQ series 1 (136).
The Epson emulation works.
Set the dip switches at the rear as follows: 
SW1
DIP 1 – on
DIP 2 – off
DIP 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 – off

SW2   (sw2-1,2,3 use different settings for various languages – setting shown is American English)
DIP 1, 2, 3 – on
DIP 4 – off
DIP 5 – on
DIP 6, 7, 8  -reserved
DIP 9 – OFF
DIP 10 reserved
Install it in win 7 64 bit as an Epson lq series 1 (136), and reboot.
I have both the user manual and the programmers manual.